# xamarin renderer invalid cast

Tags: xamarin, custom-renderer

In order to be able to create a styling that needs to be done natively in the Xamarin environment, I am using a custom renderer. On the android side, I am receiving an `System.InvalidCastException`, and I do not know how to fix this issue. I am currently wrapping an `Android.Widget.StackView` due to [this guys](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/35979/default-constructor-not-found-of-typemyclass) suggestion on a previous error I was getting (no default constructor takes 0 arguments error). The error does not seem to happen due to declaration or instantiation, but rather when I add it to the ContentView and happens at the return (found by commenting out the line as shown below).

```cs
        MainPage = new ContentPage {
            Content = new StackLayout {
                VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center,
                Children = {
                    item1,
                    item2,
                    item3,
                    item4,
                    item5,
                    item6,
                    //rendererIWantToAdd,//taking out this line make it work. adding it breaks it
                }
            }
        };
```

## Code

### RendererView

```cs
public class RendererView :  View
{

    public static readonly BindableProperty ImageProperty = BindableProperty.Create(
        propertyName: "Src",
        returnType: typeof(string),
        declaringType: typeof(string),
        defaultValue: ""
    );
    public String Src
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(ImageProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ImageProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly BindableProperty TextProperty = BindableProperty.Create(
        propertyName: "Text",
        returnType: typeof(string),
        declaringType: typeof(string),
        defaultValue: "Hello World"
    );
    public String Text
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(TextProperty); }
        set { SetValue(TextProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly BindableProperty ColorProperty = BindableProperty.Create(
        propertyName: "Color",
        returnType: typeof(string),
        declaringType: typeof(string),
        defaultValue: "#AAAAAA"
    );
    public String Color
    {
        get { return (string) GetValue(ColorProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ColorProperty, value); }
    }
}
```

### RendererViewAndroid

```cs
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(Project.RendererView), typeof(stackViewWrapper))]
namespace Project.Droid
{
    public class RendererViewAndroid : ViewRenderer<RendererView, stackViewWrapper>
    {

        Android.Widget.TextView label;
        Android.Widget.ImageView image;

        protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<RendererView> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);
            if (Control == null)
            {
                createItem(e);
            }

            if (e.OldElement != null)
            {

                unsubscribe(e);
            }

            if (e.NewElement != null)
            {
                subscribe(e);
            }



        }


        protected void createItem(ElementChangedEventArgs<RendererView> e)
        {


            SetNativeControl(new stackViewWrapper());
            label = new Android.Widget.TextView(Context)
            {
                Text = Element.Text
            };

            image = new Android.Widget.ImageView(Context);
            if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Element.Src))
            {
                Context.Resources.GetBitmapAsync(Element.Src).ContinueWith((t) =>
                {
                    var bitmap = t.Result;
                    if (bitmap != null)
                    {
                        image.SetImageBitmap(bitmap);
                        bitmap.Dispose();
                    }
                }, TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());

            }
            else {
            //  // clear the image
                image.SetImageBitmap(null);
            }


            Control.AddView(image);
            Control.AddView(label);



        }
        protected void subscribe(ElementChangedEventArgs<RendererView> e)
        {

        }
        protected void unsubscribe(ElementChangedEventArgs<RendererView> e)
        {

        }





        protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            base.Dispose(disposing);
        }





    }


    public  class stackViewWrapper : Android.Views.View
    {
        public stackViewWrapper() : base(Android.App.Application.Context)
        {
        }
    }
}
```

## Error Stack Trace

> System.InvalidCastException: Specified cast is not valid.
>     at at (wrapper castclass) System.Object:__castclass_with_cache (object,intptr,intptr)
>     at Xamarin.Forms.Registrar`1[TRegistrable].GetHandler (System.Type type) [0x0001b] in C:\BuildAgent2\work\aad494dc9bc9783\Xamarin.Forms.Core\Registrar.cs:24
>     at Xamarin.Forms.Registrar`1[TRegistrable].GetHandler[TOut] (System.Type type) [0x00000] in C:\BuildAgent2\work\aad494dc9bc9783\Xamarin.Forms.Core\Registrar.cs:29
>     at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.Platform.CreateRenderer (Xamarin.Forms.VisualElement element) [0x00006] in C:\BuildAgent2\work\aad494dc9bc9783\Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android\Platform.cs:281
>     at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.VisualElementPackager.AddChild (Xamarin.Forms.VisualElement view, IVisualElementRenderer oldRenderer, Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.RendererPool pool, Boolean sameChildren) [0x00023] in C:\BuildAgent2\work\aad494dc9bc9783\Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android\VisualElementPackager.cs:72
>     at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.VisualElementPackager.SetElement (Xamarin.Forms.VisualElement oldElement, Xamarin.Forms.VisualElement newElement) [0x00104] in C:\BuildAgent2\work\aad494dc9bc9783\Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android\VisualElementPackager.cs:204
>     at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.VisualElementPackager.Load () [0x00000] in C:\BuildAgent2\work\aad494dc9bc9783\Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android\VisualElementPackager.cs:56
>     at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.VisualElementRenderer`1[TElement].SetPackager (Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.VisualElementPackager packager) [0x00007] in C:\BuildAgent2\work\aad494dc9bc9783\Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android\VisualElementRenderer.cs:327
>     at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.VisualElementRenderer`1[TElement].SetElement (Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.TElement element) [0x00111] in C:\BuildAgent2\work\aad494dc9bc9783\Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android\VisualElementRenderer.cs:195
>     at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.VisualElementRenderer`1[TElement].Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.IVisualElementRenderer.SetElement (Xamarin.Forms.VisualElement element) [0x00027] in C:\BuildAgent2\work\aad494dc9bc9783\Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android\VisualElementRenderer.cs:128
>     at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.Platform.CreateRenderer (Xamarin.Forms.VisualElement element) [0x0001f] in C:\BuildAgent2\work\aad494dc9bc9783\Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android\Platform.cs:282
>     at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.VisualElementPackager.AddChild (Xamarin.Forms.VisualElement view, IVisualElementRenderer oldRenderer, Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.RendererPool pool, Boolean sameChildren) [0x00023] in C:\BuildAgent2\work\aad494dc9bc9783\Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android\VisualElementPackager.cs:72
>     at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.VisualElementPackager.SetElement (Xamarin.Forms.VisualElement oldElement, Xamarin.Forms.VisualElement newElement) [0x00104] in C:\BuildAgent2\work\aad494dc9bc9783\Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android\VisualElementPackager.cs:204
>     at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.VisualElementPackager.Load () [0x00000] in C:\BuildAgent2\work\aad494dc9bc9783\Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android\VisualElementPackager.cs:56
>     at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.VisualElementRenderer`1[TElement].SetPackager (Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.VisualElementPackager packager) [0x00007] in C:\BuildAgent2\work\aad494dc9bc9783\Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android\VisualElementRenderer.cs:327
>     at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.VisualElementRenderer`1[TElement].SetElement (Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.TElement element) [0x00111] in C:\BuildAgent2\work\aad494dc9bc9783\Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android\VisualElementRenderer.cs:195
>     at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.VisualElementRenderer`1[TElement].Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.IVisualElementRenderer.SetElement (Xamarin.Forms.VisualElement element) [0x00027] in C:\BuildAgent2\work\aad494dc9bc9783\Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android\VisualElementRenderer.cs:128
>     at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.Platform.CreateRenderer (Xamarin.Forms.VisualElement element) [0x0001f] in C:\BuildAgent2\work\aad494dc9bc9783\Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android\Platform.cs:282
>     at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.Platform.AddChild (Xamarin.Forms.VisualElement view, Boolean layout) [0x00015] in C:\BuildAgent2\work\aad494dc9bc9783\Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android\Platform.cs:518
>     at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.Platform.SetPage (Xamarin.Forms.Page newRoot) [0x00089] in C:\BuildAgent2\work\aad494dc9bc9783\Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android\Platform.cs:406
>     at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.FormsApplicationActivity.InternalSetPage (Xamarin.Forms.Page page) [0x000b7] in C:\BuildAgent2\work\aad494dc9bc9783\Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android\FormsApplicationActivity.cs:286
>     at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.FormsApplicationActivity.SetMainPage () [0x00000] in C:\BuildAgent2\work\aad494dc9bc9783\Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android\FormsApplicationActivity.cs:305
>     at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.FormsApplicationActivity.LoadApplication (Xamarin.Forms.Application application) [0x0002d] in C:\BuildAgent2\work\aad494dc9bc9783\Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android\FormsApplicationActivity.cs:108
>     at Project.Droid.MainActivity.OnCreate (Android.OS.Bundle bundle) [0x000ae] in /Users/ryan/project-app-xamarin/Project/Project.Droid/MainActivity.cs:47
>     at Android.App.Activity.n_OnCreate_Landroid_os_Bundle_ (IntPtr jnienv, IntPtr native__this, IntPtr native_savedInstanceState) [0x00011] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/3340/4e275588/source/monodroid/src/Mono.Android/platforms/android-23/src/generated/Android.App.Activity.cs:2426
>     at at (wrapper dynamic-method) System.Object:688deba4-7150-4f17-9062-10e53a94164c (intptr,intptr,intptr)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if this is actually the root of your issue but it will certainly cause you problems afterwards if it is not.

In your `RendererView` all of your binding properties should have their `declaringType` set to the class that they are being declared in, which would be `RendererView`.

For example your first binding property should look like:

```
public static readonly BindableProperty ImageProperty = BindableProperty.Create(
    propertyName: "Src",
    returnType: typeof(string),
    declaringType: typeof(RendererView),
    defaultValue: ""
);
```

Then do the same for all the rest. If that doesn't fix it, definitely let me know.

Edit: According to the OP's comment below, the initial error came from the `ExportRenderer` line, which needed to declare the `RendererView` instead of the `stackViewWrapper` like so:

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(Project.RendererView), typeof(RendererViewAndroid))]
```

Comment: This unfortunately did not fix my error. I can definitely see how that would have caused me errors later on. What I am wondering is if the types that I am trying to use do not match up. For instance, I am using View with Android.Views.View. maybe they do not match up for renderers? Also, all of the code in my `createItem()` method has been commented out and it still errors out. That is all the info I have right now.

Comment: Your comment was almost on track. It was actually a different line though. In `RendererViewAndroid` The first shown line is actually the issues. The line should be `[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(Project.RendererView), typeof(**RendererViewAndroid**))]`, not type of wrapper. I will let you update your answer to make it the most complete (instead of making one myself) and I will mark that one right. Thank you very much!

Comment: @R293 Glad I could help a little. Edited my answer to include your answer as well. Thanks for commenting back with the actual answer to the issue.

Comment: Worst things that I always see is when the OP of any program error thread goes "lol jk got it" and never explains how. I would rather not be that.

Comment: @R293 Haha I completely agree